# Does empty synchronized(this){} have any meaning to memory visibility between threads?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, volatile, memory-model

I read this in an upvoted comment on StackOverflow:

> But if you want to be safe, you can add simple synchronized(this) {}
>   at the end of you @PostConstruct [method]

[note that variables were NOT volatile]

I was thinking that **happens-before** is forced only if both write and read is executed in `synchronized` block or at least read is volatile.

Is the quoted sentence correct? Does an empty `synchronized(this) {}` block flush all variables changed in current method to "general visible" memory?

**Please consider some scenerios**

- what if second thread never calls lock on `this`? (suppose that second thread reads in other methods). Remember that question is about: **flush changes to other threads**, not **give other threads a way (synchronized) to poll changes made by original thread**. Also no-synchronization in other methods is very likely in Spring `@PostConstruct` context - as original comment says.
- is memory visibility of changes forced only in second and subsequent calls by another thread? (remember that this synchronized block is a **last** call in our method) - this would mark this way of synchronization as very bad practice (stale values in first call)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All writes that occur prior to a `monitor exit` are visible to all threads after a `monitor enter`.

A `synchronized(this){}` can be turned into bytecode like

```
monitorenter
monitorexit
```

So if you have a bunch of writes prior to the `synchronized(this){}` they would have occurred before the `monitorexit`.

This brings us to the next point of my first sentence.

> visible to all threads after a `monitor enter`

So now, in order for a thread to ensure the writes ocurred it must execute the same synchronization ie `synchornized(this){}`.  This will issue at the very least a `monitorenter` and establish your happens before ordering.

---

So to answer your question

> Does an empty synchronized(this) {} block flush all variables changed
>   in current method to "general visible" memory?

Yes, as long as you maintain the same synchronization when you want to read those non-volatile variables.

To address your other questions

> what if second thread never calls lock on this? (suppose that second
>   thread reads in other methods). Remember that question is about: flush
>   changes to other threads, not give other threads a way (synchronized)
>   to poll changes made by original thread. Also no-synchronization in
>   other methods is very likely in Spring @PostConstruct context

Well in this case using `synchronized(this)` without any other context is relatively useless.  There is no happens-before relationship and it's in theory just as useful as not including it.

> is memory visibility of changes forced only in second and subsequent
>   calls by another thread? (remember that this synchronized block is a
>   last call in our method) - this would mark this way of synchronization
>   as very bad practice (stale values in first call)

Memory visibility is forced by the first thread calling `synchronized(this)`, in that it will write directly to memory.  Now, this doesn't necessarily mean each threads needs to read directly from memory.  They can still read from their own processor caches.  Having a thread call `synchronized(this)` ensures it pulls the value of the field(s) from memory and retrieve most up to date value.

Comment: But, am I right if I say: when second thread call this method FIRST time after changes, it can get a stale value, because 100%-sure update occurs when second thread is exiting this method (empty synchronized is last in method), so changes will be 100%-sure progagated only in SECOND other-thread call. am I right?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.  So if the `synchornized` is at the end like you state and another thread enters the method any of the non-volatile variables can certainly be stale until that thread reaches the `synchronized` block.

Comment: That being said, the reasoning also applies to any thread reading those non-volatile variables without having a `synchronized` block before reading (even if not in the `@PostConstruct` method).

Answer (score 16):

Much of what's written about this on SO, including many of the answers/comments in this thread, are, sadly, wrong.

The key rule in the Java Memory Model that applies here is: an unlock operation on a given monitor *happens-before* a subsequent lock operation on that same monitor.  If only one thread ever acquires the lock, it has no meaning.  If the VM can prove that the lock object is thread-confined, it can elide any fences it might otherwise emit.

The quote you highlight assumes that releasing a lock acts as a full fence.  And sometimes that might be true, but you can't count on it.  So your skeptical questions are well-founded.

See [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://amzn.to/1jyE5Kx), Ch 16 for more on the Java Memory Model.